# Getting error while using two cursors

Tags: database, plsqldeveloper

Getting error while using two cursors

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (45: 48): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol 
        "TX_COM_LOCATION" when expecting one of the following:

       := . ( @ % ;
    The symbol ":=" was substituted for 
    "TX_COM_LOCATION" to continue.
```

Please help

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COM_LOCATION_TXM 
IS
BEGIN
DECLARE
 CURSOR TXM_COM_LOCATION IS
 SELECT col1,col2,col3 from TBL_SAR_SALAS_1 A;
CURSOR TX_COM_LOCATION is 
select  col1,col2,col3 from TBL_LOCALES B;
TMP_TXM  TXM_COM_LOCATION%ROWTYPE;
Begin
IF NOT TXM_COM_LOCATION%ISOPEN
THEN
OPEN TXM_COM_LOCATION;
END IF;
FETCH TXM_COM_LOCATION INTO TMP_TXM;
EXIT WHEN TXM_COM_LOCATION%NOTFOUND;
TMP_TXM  TX_COM_COCATION%ROWTYPE;
IF NOT TX_COM_LOCATION%ISOPEN
THEN

Comment: OPEN TXCOM_LOCATION;
END IF;
LOOP
FETCH TX_COM_LOCATION INTO TMP_TX;
EXIT WHEN TX_COM_LOCATION%NOTFOUND;
BEGIN
Insert statement()
END;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
commit;
END;
END  COM_LOCATION_TXM ;
/

Comment: sorry to break the code..and add it..

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COM_LOCATION_TXM IS BEGIN DECLARE CURSOR TXM_COM_LOCATION IS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TBL_SAR_SALAS_1 A;  CURSOR TX_COM_LOCATION IS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM TBL_LOCALES B;  TMP_TXM   TXM_COM_LOCATION%ROWTYPE; TMP_TXM   TX_COM_LOCATION%ROWTYPE; BEGIN IF NOT TXM_COM_LOCATION%ISOPEN THEN OPEN TXM_COM_LOCATION; END IF;  LOOP FETCH TXM_COM_LOCATION INTO TMP_TXM;  EXIT WHEN TXM_COM_LOCATION%NOTFOUND;  IF NOT TX_COM_LOCATION%ISOPEN THEN OPEN TXCOM_LOCATION; END IF;  LOOP FETCH TX_COM_LOCATION INTO TMP_TX;  EXIT WHEN TX_COM_LOCATION%NOTFOUND;  BEGIN NULL;                     -- REPLACE NULL WITH INSERT STATEMENT END; END LOOP; END LOOP;  COMMIT; END; END COM_LOCATION_TXM;

Comment: not working dear...its saying [Error] PLS-00201 (36: 10): PLS-00201: identifier 'TX_COM_COCATION' must be declared..dont know why

Comment: It's because of  mistake in type name:

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COM_LOCATION_TXM 
IS
BEGIN 
DECLARE CURSOR TXM_COM_LOCATION IS SELECT col1,col2,col3 from TBL_SAR_SALAS_1 A; 
CURSOR TX_COM_LOCATION is select col1,col2,col3 from TBL_LOCALES B; 
TMP_TXM TXM_COM_LOCATION%ROWTYPE; 
TMP_TXM TX_COM_COCATION%ROWTYPE;
Begin
IF NOT TXM_COM_LOCATION%ISOPEN 
THEN OPEN TXM_COM_LOCATION; 
END IF; 
FETCH TXM_COM_LOCATION INTO TMP_TXM;
EXIT
WHEN TXM_COM_LOCATION%NOTFOUND;

IF NOT TX_COM_LOCATION%ISOPEN 
THEN 
OPEN TXCOM_LOCATION;
END IF;
LOOP FETCH TX_COM_LOCATION INTO TMP_TX; EXIT WHEN TX_COM_LOCATION%NOTFOUND;
BEGIN Insert statement() 
END; 
END LOOP; 
END LOOP; 
commit; 
END; 
END COM_LOCATION_TXM ;
```